# Databricks Pyspark: How to mask columns with personal information in a data frame use ***

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

There is a data frame created which contains several columns with personal information.
To protect data privacy, we need to mask these values, no need to show the full name or full mobile phone number. sometimes the value is null, then just keep blank or null.
How should I update the data frame?

existing data frame df:

| Full Name | phone | E-mail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wang Yang | 13845692510 | abcefg@hotmail.com |
| Yi Tian | 15901785632 |  |
| Jin Chen |  | 58963251@qq.com |

I hope to get the below result

| Full Name | phone | E-mail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wang **** | 138****2510 | a*****@hotmail.com |
| Yi **** | 159****5632 |  |
| Jin **** |  | 5*******@qq.com |

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Mask Columns") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [("Wang Yang", "13845692510", "abcefg@hotmail.com"),
        ("Yi Tian", "15901785632", ""),
        ("Jin Chen", "", "58963251@qq.com")]

# Create data frame
columns = ["Full Name", "phone", "E-mail"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Define mask expressions
mask_name = "IF(`Full Name` != '', concat(substring(`Full Name`, 1, instr(`Full Name`, ' ')), '****'), '')"
mask_phone = "IF(phone != '', concat(substring(phone, 1, 3), '****', substring(phone, 8, 4)), '')"
mask_email = "IF(`E-mail` != '', concat(substring(`E-mail`, 1, 1), '*****', substring(`E-mail`, instr(`E-mail`, '@'), length(`E-mail`))), '')"

# Apply mask expressions
df_masked = df.withColumn("Full Name", expr(mask_name)) \
    .withColumn("phone", expr(mask_phone)) \
    .withColumn("E-mail", expr(mask_email))

# Show masked data frame
df_masked.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried and it works well.